# How can you tell if bash is being accessed from a remote machine?

Tags: bash

I am trying to write out a dynamic bash profile for a few machines, and was wondering if there is a variable that allows `.bashrc` if it is being accessed remotely. I've seen a few examples using X variables, but that is irrelevant to both machines.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
if [ "$SSH_CONNECTION" ]; then
  echo I am remote
else
  echo I am local
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

When you connect via ssh, your bash process is a child of sshd ($PPID is a variable of bash's parent process - ssh that is, if you connect remotely). You can check for that:

```
if ps ax | grep ^$PPID'.*sshd' &> /dev/null; then  
  # do your stuff
fi
```

Edit: I was bored and used `time` to get execution times and found out that this version apparently is a couple of milliseconds faster:

```
if grep ^sshd: /proc/$PPID/cmdline &> /dev/null; then
  # do your stuff
fi
```

Comment: Awesome. This is going to sound crazy but that has no notable performance hit, right?

Comment: Not really. You can run ps ax from your shell to see how long it takes - it just lists all running programs. And, well, grep is fast.

Comment: I added an alternative version that only uses `grep` and the virtual `/proc` file system. A bit faster no, but both is what I would call 'instant'

Comment: Impressive! Is `13785` a constant?

Comment: UH DAMN! I accidentally substituted my value of $PPID, sorry. I'll change it now.